# Selenium with Python Exception when trying to get unicode text

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

I'm trying to get an Hebrew text out of an HTML page using the code:

```
text = msg.find_element_by_class_name('selectable-text').text
```

The code works great as long as we're dealing with English text.
After some searching i've tried adding a utf-8 tag on the top, but it did not do anything:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
```

Putting in random Hebrew text into a variable and do stuff with it did not raise any problems, therefore I suspect the problem may be with Selenium.

The debug.log I received was:

```
[1210/131919:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(114)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.  (0xc0000022)
[1210/131919:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 11172 not found in process
[1210/131919:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(56)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
```

What do you think?

I'm running Python 3.5.2

Comment: What do you get in the `text` variable when assigning Hebrew into it?

Comment: Just tried it with ynet.co.il and it works perfectly fine. hebrew_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("title").find_element_by_tag_name('span').text.
Which OS are you using?